# Kafka recommended system configuration

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm expecting our influx in to `Kafka` to raise to around `2 TB/day` over a period of time. I'm planning to setup a Kafka cluster with `2 brokers` (each running on separate system). What is the recommended hardware configuration for handling `2 TB/day` ?

Comment: I don't believe there is a specific answer for this. I suggest you build your kafka system and test it. You'll eventually find what is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

To use as a base you could look here: https://docs.confluent.io/4.1.1/installation/system-requirements.html#hardware

You need to know the amount of messages you get per second/hour because this will determine the size of your cluster. For HD, it's not necessary to get SSD because the system will use RAM to store the data first. Still you could need quite speed hard disk to ensure that the flushing process of the queue will not slow your system.

I would also recommend to use 3 kafka broker and 3 or 4 zookeeper server too.